# Checking student submission marked as "Excused" in Google Classroom

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace, google-classroom

There is a new feature in Google Classroom that allows the teacher to mark a student submission to an assignment as excused. This renders the submission "Graded" but allows the grade to remain undefined. However, it is unclear how to check for this status on the script side. I would expect the status to be exposed somewhere in the StudentSubmission object, but I can't find it there. The "Excused" status also does not seem to be included yet in Google documentation. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The ability to mark a student submission as "excused" in the Classroom app was announced here: https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2023/12/excuse-assignments-in-google-classroom.html.

The Classroom API **does not currently support** a means of detecting this, and there is an [open request for support](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/316938115). I would encourage you to upvote that issue and add any details about how this impacts your organization there.